# How can I assign a child class to a base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, variable-assignment

I know there are solved questions related to this issue, but I still can't figure out how to resolve my problem.

I have something like this:

```
class Base
{
   static Base* createBase()
   {
      Base *b = new Base();
      ... //does a lot of weird things
      return b;
   }
}

class Child : public Base
{
   static Child* createChild()
   {
      Child *c = createBase(); // error
      return c;          
   }
}
```

I know why it doesn't work, but I have to find a way to do it. The createBase function does a lot of things so I don't want to recode it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, why do you have to find a way to do that?  Seriously.  You know you can't do that, and you why you can't do that.  Why do you absolutely have to have a `Child *` that doesn't point at a `Child`?

Comment: Another thought:  Does `Child` have to be a child of `Base`?  Could it just contain a `Base`?  (Quite possibly not, but you haven't said enough for me to know.)

Comment: If you move the "weird things" into the `Base` constructor, then `createChild` can just `return new Child`.

Answer (score 9):

Why do you expect that to work? You can't treat a `Base` object as if it were a `Child` object, because the `Child` class might have all sorts of additional data that `Base` does not.

In order to get the effect you're looking for, there are two ways to do it:

The first way, and probably the best idea, is to move the logic from `createBase` into the `Base` constructor. The `Base` constructor will run whether you're creating a `Base` or something derived from it. It looks like you're trying to do the work of initializing the base object, and that's exactly what constructors are for!

If for some reason this will not work in your case, the other option is to create a protected `initialize` method in `Base` which accepts a `Base*` and does all the work that you are currently doing in `createBase`, e.g.

```
class Base
{
  public:

   static Base* createBase()
   {
       Base* b = new Base();
       initialize(b);
       return b;
   }

  protected:

   static void initialize(Base* b)
   {
      ... //does a lot of weird things
   }
}

class Child : public Base
{
  public:
   static Child* createChild()
   {
      Child *c = new Child(); 
      initialize(c):
      return c;          
   }
}
```

Note that this works since, while you can't treat a `Base*` as if it were a `Child*`, you *can* go the other way and treat a `Child*` as if it were a `Base*`, because the `Child` class is guaranteed to have at least everything that the `Base` class does, due to the nature of inheritance.

**Edit:** I saw you post in a comment to another answer that you cannot modify the definition of `Base`. In that case, you are completely out of luck and you will have to accept the need to copy-and-paste, given the restrictions in play. You are not going to be able to call `createBase` and get back a pointer to an object of any type other than `Base` if you cannot modify its code.

Comment: I'd argue you are better off making initialise a virtual member function rather than a static as this would allow you to add any "further" intialisation to the child class while still calling the base class function from the derived class function ... but other than that good answer :)

Comment: @Goz True, but for the same reason the code should be in the constructor in the first place.

Comment: All he needs is to put things in a constructor. Nothing else is required.

Answer (score 2):

overloading new for Base class might solve your issue.

class UTIL{

```
static size_t size;
```

public:
    static void setSize(size_t t)
        {
        //mutex protection
        size  = t;
    }

```
static size_t getsize(); // should only be called from inside new of class A
```

};

class A
{
    int i;

public:
    static A* createA()
    {

```
    A* a = new A();
    a->i = 10;
    return a;
}
```

void* operator new (size_t  size) throw (const char *){

void * p = malloc(UTIL::getsize());

if (p == 0)  throw "allocation failure";

return p;

}

void operator delete (void *p){

free(p);
}

};

size_t UTIL::size = sizeof(A);

size_t UTIL::getsize()
{

```
    //mutex protection
    size_t tmp = size;
    size = sizeof(A);
    return tmp;
```

}

class B
{

public:
        int j;
    static B* createB()
    {

```
           //take mutex

    UTIL::setSize(sizeof(B));
    B* b = (B*)(A::createA());
    b->j = 20;
    //release Mutex
    return b;
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
Child *c = new Child();
```

Otherwise you are trying to create a Base class instance and call it a Child.

RE your comment:

Perhaps you could change

```
static Base* createBase();

static void createBase(Base *b);
```

If you pass the instance into this method you could use it with both Child and Base

for example:

```
Base *b = new Base();
Base::createBase(b);

Child *c = new Child();
Base::createBase(c);
```

or alternatively

```
static Base *createBase(Base *b = NULL){
    if(b == NULL){
        b = new Base;
    }
    //do your stuff
    return b;
```

and for the child:

```
static Child* createChild(){
    Child *c = new Child;
    createBase(c);
    return c;
```

This way you can use both:

```
b = Base::createBase();
c = Child::createChild();
```

Comment: But I want to do all those weird stuff createBase does.... without copy/paste since its a very large method.

Comment: Could that weird stuff be moved to the Base constructor instead of the static method?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I can't modify the Base class.

Comment: If you can't modify the Base class you may have to duplicate the behavior in that method then.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should re-define createBase as follows:

```
template< class TheClass > static TheClass* create()
{
  TheClass *ret = new TheClass();
  ... //does a lot of weird things
  return ret;
}
```

You can then create an object as follows:

```
Child* pChild = create< Child >();
```

This may not be appropriate depending what the "weird" things are but its one possible way of solving your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Don't the "weird" things belong in the Base constructor. Then by constructing the Child your base gets properly constructed?

Otherwise just refactor the code into a method you call from both places - definately don't copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructors to do the work for you:

```
class Base
{
   Base()
   {
     // does a lot of weird things
   }

  static Base* createBase()
  {
     return new Base();
  }

};

class Child : public Base
{
   Child()
   {
      // Do child's weird things here        
   }

  static Child* createChild()
  {
     return new Child();
  }
};

Base *instance1 = new Child();  // Works as expected
Base *instance2 = Child::createChild();  // Works as expected
Base *instance3 = new Base();  // Works as expected
Base *instance4 = Base::createBase();  // Works as expected
```

**EDIT:**
If you can't modify the Base class, you shouldn't derive from it this way. The class is apparently meant to have its own functionality and the static construction method suggests some more complex usage. You might want to use the Decorator design pattern instead of inheritance in this case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
class Base
{
public:
   static Base* createBase()
   {
      Base *b = new Base();
      //does a lot of weird things
      return b;
   }
};

class Child
{
   protected:
   Base* m_basePtr;

public:
   operator Base&(){return *m_basePtr;}
   static Child* createChild()
   {
      Child *c=new Child;
      c->m_basePtr=Base::createBase();
      return c;          
   }
};
```

but you have to delete the pointer at the destructor

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
class Base
{
  Base()
  {
         ... //does a lot of weird things
  }
};

class Child : public Base
{
  Child Child() // This calls the base constructor auto-magically
  {
  }
}

int main()
{
    Child  childOne;
    Base   baseOne;

    Child*  childPtr = new Child();
    Base*   basePtr1 = new Child();
    Base*   basePtr2 = new Base();
}
```